# Can I access the function body of an event listener using nodeJS jsdom

Tags: dom, jsdom

I am using jsdom with nodeJS. I load in a large HTML document, and am using jQuery to navigate the DOM. I have a case where I have an element, and I need to access the function body of an event listener (onclick). The event listener was added in the source HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://<rest-of-url>'); return false;"></a>
```

The onclick attribute of the DOM element is undefined.

btw: what I really want to do is get the URL (please note that <rest-of-url> is not what is in the source, a real URL spec is there) that is specified in the source.

Comment: I have hacked a way to get the info I want, but I wonder if there is something more stable: e._attributes._nodes.onclick._childNodes[0]._text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.getAttribute('onclick')` doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks Elijah. It does work. I don't know why I hadn't tried that -- too obvious!